# Adding xml comments to methods, properties, etc quickly in vs 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Assume I have 10 Methods and 10 Properties.  Is there a way to add the xml comments (///) to all 10 Methods and 10 Properties at once in VS 2008 or do I have to type /// for each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This little tool is very useful [Ghost Doc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/).

Comment: I use this all the time and love it. It's so much easier than the default behavior of VS!

Answer (score 2):

Well you have to actually type text into each one anyway, so typing `///` each time isn't really any extra work. I hope you aren't just inserting the stubs and leaving them there.

Comment: No, I was just curious if there was a quick way to add the all the stubs at once.

Comment: I find it easier to just start /// and type the summary right away. It places the cursor in the right spot for that immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a powershell (scripting language with syntax pretty similar to C#) script to do that for you.